# All Pages of Website are Flickering

Tags: joomla

I don't know why, but all the pages of my website made in joomla are flickering.
Do you guys have idea how can i fix this issue?

I tried unplushing some plugins but still not work

http://www.btoresearch.com/

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its not flickering. Clear your browser cache.

Comment: This problem is on a few devices, and i didn't find a commom thing between the devices. I already cleaned the cache on my browser but it didn't work